# Making SymPy symbols refer to the set of real numbers only

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When working with symbols in Sympy it would sometimes be useful for the library to understand that a symbol refers only to a certain subset of the complex numbers. Example: `theta = sympy.symbols('theta')` when fed into the sin function and taking the complex conjugate `sympy.conjugate(sympy.sin(theta))` would ideally yield `sin(theta)` since `theta` will only ever be a real number and the complex conjugate only negates the imaginary component of a complex number. Instead, it gives `sin(conjugate(theta))` which indicates that sympy has no semantic understanding that `theta` will never have a non-zero imaginary component.

This can lead to problems since `sin(theta)` is not necessarily the same as `sin(conjugate(theta))`. Is there a way to tell SymPy that a given symbol is a real number such that `sin(conjugate(theta))` automatically simplifies to `sin(theta)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `real=True` upon declaration, i.e.:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import conjugate, sin

theta = sym.Symbol('theta', real=True)

sin(conjugate(theta))
# evaluates to: sin(theta)

conjugate(sin(theta))
# evaluates to: sin(theta)
```

while:

```
zeta = sym.Symbol('zeta')

sin(conjugate(zeta))
# evaluates to: sin(conjugate(zeta))

conjugate(sin(zeta))
# evaluates to: conjugate(sin(zeta))
```

if the symbol is not declared as `real`.

**EDIT**: This could be found in one of the [older tutorials](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/tutorial.html). I am not sure why this was not covered in newer tutorials, but as of SymPy 1.4 it works.